# Way on generating a truth table for arbitrary number of variables

Tags: haskell

How does one generate a truth table of all possible true/false combinations for an input like `["a", "b", "c"]`.

I find it really hard to think about it recursively!

For example:
Input: `["a", "b"]`
Output:

```
        [ [("a",True), ("b",True)], 
          [("a",True), ("b",False)],
          [("a",False), ("b",True)],
          [("a",False), ("b",False)] ]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How do you represent truth tables for variables of type `a`?

```
type TruthTable a = [(a, Bool)]

truthTables :: [a] -> [TruthTable a]
```

What is your truth table for **no** variables? There is only one: the one that contains no variable assignments.

```
truthTables [] = [[]]
```

How do you construct all possible truth tables for variables `v:vs`, given the truth tables for `vs`? You take every possible truth table for `vs`, and every possible assignment for `v`, and combine them:

```
truthTables (v:vs) = [(v, b):others | b <- [True, False], others <- truthTables vs]
```

We could have also written it using the `Monad` instance of `[]`:

```
truthTables [] = return []
truthTables (v:vs) = do
  this <- [True, False]
  them <- truthTables vs
  return (this:them)
```